# How can I break a mesh into pieces?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've puchased a big interior scene from a 3d marketplace.

To optimize it in Unity (using Occlusion culling), I need to break the meshes into pieces, without modifying the structure.

Is there any blender command to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In *Edit Mode* you can mark the polygons you want to separate and press <kbd>P</kbd> , then *Separate by Selection.*

Pressing <kbd>L</kbd> while hovering over a mesh in *Edit Mode* will select connected mesh parts.